# How to resolve this #606 application is blocked error in facebook ad network?

Tags: android, admob, facebook-ads-api, facebook-audience-network

I am using this version of fb ad network sdk in my app.

```
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.27.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.27.0'
```

Few days back my app was removed from the google playstore. But Soon after getting live on play store , it is able to serve ads from admob but not from fb ad network.
It is showing error as [image: logcat error]

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i Have appealed in at the Facebook developer site and reported the  issue and after 7-10 days they emailed me the update with the issue . From there i have followed up them and shared my concerns or what ever issues you are facing.
Appeal here for your app at Facebook Audience Network : [FAcebook business manager](https://business.facebook.com/)

here you can select your app and below you will find a contact audience network link at below in the monetisation manager page.